# Warning: set it to a single string instead

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

What does this warning mean? How can I get rid of this?

```
Support for setting the 'text.latex.preamble' or 'pgf.preamble' rcParam to a list of strings is deprecated since 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later; set it to a single string instead.
  plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r"\usepackage{bm}", [r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r"\usepackage{bm}"], [r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]

params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 28,
          'font.family' : 'lmodern',
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

Comment: The warning says that after two matplotlib version releases, your approach will not work anymore. If you just need your code to work now, you do not have to change anything. If this is supposed to work in a year or two, you should address this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation, https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.3.0/deprecations.html#setting-rcparams-text-latex-preamble-default-or-rcparams-pdf-preamble-to-non-strings, setting `rcParams['text.latex.preamble']` to a list of strings is no longer the correct way.

To fix this, you should replace

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r"\usepackage{bm}"], [r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
```

to be

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r"\usepackage{bm} \usepackage{amsmath}"
```